# Induced isomorphism between $H^{1,0}(X)$ and $H^{1,0}(Y)$ implies the induced isomorphism between $H^{0,1}(X)$ and $H^{0,1}(Y)$?

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory, complex-manifolds

Let $X,Y$ be two compact Kahler manifolds and $f:X\to Y$ is a holomorphic map. If the induced map $f^*:H^1(X)\to H^1(Y)$'s restriction $f^*|_{H^{1,0}}$ an isomorphism from $H^{1,0}(X)\to H^{1,0}(Y)$, can we also conclude that $f^*$'s restriction $f^*|_{H^{0,1}}$ is an isomorphism from $H^{0,1}(X)\to H^{0,1}(Y)$?

Comment: Isn't the complex conjugaison an isomorphism from holomorphic to anti-holomorphic one forms ? (sending $g(z)dz$ to $\overline{g(z)} d\overline{z}$). And (from the harmonic conjugate) an harmonic real one-form is the real part of an holomorphic one-form.

Comment: @reuns $\bar{g(z)}$ is not holomorphic, then I wonder why $\bar{g(z)}d\bar{z}$ is an $(0,1)$-form?

Comment: It is anti-holomorphic and $\overline{g(z)}d\overline{z}$ produces the conjugate value of $g(z)dz$ when integrated on a curve . If (in local chart $s$) $\overline{\omega}=\sum_{j=1}^{\dim(Y)} \overline{h_j(s)}d \overline{s_j} \in H^{0,1}(Y)$ then $f^* \overline{\omega}=\sum_{j=1}^{\dim(Y)} \overline{h_j(f(z))}d \overline{f(z)_j}  \in H^{0,1}(X)$, $\omega =\sum_{j=1}^{\dim(Y)} h_j(s)d s_j \in H^{1,0}(Y)$, $f^* \omega=\sum_{j=1}^{\dim(Y)} h_j(f(z))d f(z)_j \in H^{1,0}(X)$.

Comment: @reuns I am a little confused with the definition, can I say elements of $\epsilon^{0,1}(X)$ are called holomorphic $(0,1)$-forms, which are elements of the $\sum f_id\bar{z_i}$, where $f_i$ is holomorphic, while anti-holomorphic $1$-forms are different, they are elements of $\overline{H^0(X,\Omega_X)}$, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conjugation map on differential forms induces an isomorphism $H^{p,q} = H^{q,p}$ for complex manifolds. As long as $f$ respects the complex structures this isomorphism is natural in $f$, you can check it commutes locally.

Comment: What do you mean by $$ respects the complex structures?

Comment: Just that $f$ is holomorphic, equivalently the derivative is a complex linear map